# Laravel/Lumen queue:listen not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen-5.2

I am able to queue up jobs in redis as I checked redis manually. I'm also aware that i need both predis and illuminate\redis

`"predis/predis": "^1.0",
        "illuminate/redis": "5.2.*"`

which i have included and tested

```
$app->get('/cache/predis', function () use ($app) {
    $client = new Predis\Client();
    $client->set('foo', 'bar');
    $value = $client->get('foo');
    return response()->json($value);
});
$app->get('/cache/redis', function () use ($app) {

    $cache = $app['cache'];
    $cache->store('redis')->put('bar', 'baz', 10);
    $value = $cache>store('redis')->get('bar');
    return response()->json($value);
});
```

However when I run: `php artisan queue:listen redis'

it tells me:

  `[InvalidArgumentException]
  No connector for []`

Any idea why? Both my `config/database.php` and `config/queue.php` are default configuration

Answer (score 0):

In the config/queue.php you need to specify which queue you are using

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sync'),
```

In this line (top of queue.php) have you specified you are using the redis details?

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'redis'),
```

Comment: I have tried both. due to `env('QUEUE_DRIVER','sync');` It takes it from my `.env` file and that one is set to redis